# Jmeter - Testing with 100 User while reading Links from CSV file

Tags: jmeter

I just started using Jmeter recently.

**What I want:**
I want to run a test of 100 users by getting links from CSV file.

**How I am doing:**
I created a Test-Plan, Added Thread Group, CSV Data Config (Child to Thread group), HTTP Request.

**Given Values:**

HTTP Request Default: Url Address (Tried with both HTTP & without HTTP in protocol section)

Thread Group: User: 100

Loop: Forever

CSV Data Set Config: File Name (Full Path, the file is not in bin folder)

Variable Name: Path

Recycle on EOF: False

Stop Thread on EOF: True

HTTP Request: IP Address:

Path: ${Path}

**CSV File:**

Path

Link1

Link2

Link3

**What I am getting:** Well the test is executing but it executing all link only once (one User), it not going for 100 User

**Note:** I am running the TestPlan from Command Mode

Thanks for your Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want **each user to go through all links** in the CSV file you need to amend [`Sharing Mode`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy) setting of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to `Current Thread`

[image]

You can verify the behavior by adding [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) as request prefix/postfix

[image]

Comment: Hi, I need little more help regarding the same issue in a different scenario, Now I am running with Concurrency Thread Group with loop count 2 with "Sharing Mode: Current Thread", it reading only 2 links while I have 5 links from CSV file, When I the change sharing mode to " All Threads & Current Thread group" it reading all but only once (one user, & no Loop) without loop it working fine